# module.name_mapper.extension Flow option not working for MP3

Tags: flowtype

Here's a repository that has a reduced case:
https://github.com/bjohn465/flow-name_mapper-test/tree/3c17d1a4b9963412787b0c9e3a0ffaf51e471fb4

I want to play an audio file—in this case, an MP3 file—using an audio element.

I have configured webpack to use file-loader to load the MP3 file. This loader will copy the file to the output directory and return the public URL to the file. So, after `import sound from './bell.mp3'`, `sound` will be a string with the URL to the MP3 file.

My `.flowconfig` looks like this:

```
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension='mp3' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow-typed/mp3-stub.js'
```

`mp3-stub.js` looks like this:

```
// @flow
const s: string = ''
export default s
```

From what I've been able to find, this should work, but when I run Flow, I still get a "Required module not found" error:

```
Error: src/audio-player.js:3
3: import sound from './bell.mp3'
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ./bell.mp3. Required module not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the problem was with the location of the stub file (`mp3-stub.js`). I moved the stub from `flow-typed` to `flow-stubs` and updated the `.flowconfig`:

```
[options]
module.name_mapper.extension='mp3' -> '<PROJECT_ROOT>/flow-stubs/mp3-stub.js'
```

I'm assuming that since Flow uses the `flow-typed` directory for [library definitions (or "libdefs")](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/) by default, it didn't like that the stub was in that directory.

The fixed version of the reduced case is available here:
https://github.com/bjohn465/flow-name_mapper-test/tree/335456fac80dd452469645930535861a91c3c4c7

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using name_mapper with a regex instead of extension?

```
module.name_mapper='^\(.*\)\.mp3$' -> './flow-typed/mp3-stub.js'
```